# How can I QUERY data using GROUP BY and TRIM in Google Sheets?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This seems like a simple problem, but I've been googling for hours and haven't had any luck.

I have some data in column F that has data like: "test", "test ", "", "test1", "test2", "test1 ", " test2", "test1".

I want to count the number of each value, but I want to TRIM the value so that "test" and "test " get counted as the same.

Here is my query:

`=query(F2:F, "select F, count(F) WHERE F <> '' GROUP BY F ORDER BY count(F) DESC LABEL F 'Type', count(F) 'Count'")`

I would think it would look something like this, but Google Sheets throws an error:

`=query(F2:F, "select trim(F), count(F) WHERE F <> '' GROUP BY trim(F) ORDER BY count(F) DESC LABEL trim(F) 'Type', count(F) 'Count'")`

I'm hoping to get rows like this:

```
Type    Count
test    2
test1   3
test2   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just trim it before the query:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(query(TRIM(F2:F), "select Col1, count(Col1) WHERE Col1 <> '' GROUP BY Col1 ORDER BY count(Col1) DESC LABEL Col1 'Type', count(Col1) 'Count'")
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use Col1 rather than F if using an array as the query source?

Comment: Yes! I had tried this, but didn't know what column name to use. F wasn't working, so I thought maybe it would be A, but turns it's Col1. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately TRIM() is not one of the Scalar functions supported by QUERY()

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar_functions

Without knowing too much about your project, why not have another sheet that references the sheet with the extra spaces and apply the TRIM() function and QUERY() that sheet.

[image]